# ag-grid bottom row mouse events only honored in top portion of row/cells

Tags: angular, mouseevent, ag-grid-angular, ag-grid-react

I am using ag-grid-angular v26.1.0 in my angular (v13.3) application for most of my tables.  I've noticed that for the bottom row of data only in all my table objects, the mouse pointer is not 'activated' (acknowledged) for the row to process events unless the pointer is hovered near the top third of any cell in the bottom row, as opposed to anywhere in a cell like the other rows.

Since I am configuring cellClicked event handlers and row selection handlers for various tasks to select/edit data in the table, it becomes difficult to get the placement of the mouse 'just right' on the bottom row of data to acknowledge that the mouse is indeed over the row.  If I 'add' a second row of data to the table, the previously-bottom row is fine, but then the problem switches to the 'new' bottom row.  Similarly, if I sort the table and the row order changes, the problem is still only associated with the sorted bottom row.

Is this by design?  Or is this a bug of some sort in ag-grid-angular? If the former, is there a configuration setting I'm missing that would allow the 'entire' bottom row to be recognized when the mouse pointer is hovered over it?

Here's a sample of the configuration options I am typically specifying:

```
 <ag-grid-angular
    [ngClass]="gridTheme"
    domLayout="autoHeight"
    [defaultColDef]="defaultColumnDef"
    [rowData]="rowData$ | async"
    [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
    rowSelection="single"
    (selectionChanged)="onSelectionChanged()"
    [frameworkComponents]="frameworkComponents"
    (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)"
    (cellValueChanged)="onUpdateEspConfig($event)"
    (cellClicked)="onCellClicked($event)"
></ag-grid-angular>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I noticed similar functionality when I look at ag-grids on: https://www.ag-grid.com/archive/25.0.0/documentation/javascript/full-width-rows/ so I don't think this is something unique to how I'm using ag-grid.  Could this be related to an 'unshown' horizontal scroll bar?  The height that is being 'unaknowleged' seems very close to the height of the horizontal scroll bar if it was displayed.

Comment: No solution yet,  but I've figured out that it's related to my CHROME version.  I was running v105.xxxx and someone else at my org that was NOT seeing this problem was runnign v104.0.5112.102,...then we both updated to the LATEST 105 (105.0.5195.127).  I am still seeing it and my associate is ALSO NOW seeing the problem.  So it has something to do with Chrome.  I will test on some other non-Chrome browsers to see if it happens there.

Comment: Ran on a very old version of Firefox I happened to have loaded, and am NOT seeing the problem there.....so this is definitely something that popped up when updating from v104 to v105 of Chrome.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, this is something that was introduced with the current (as of this post) version of Chrome (v105.x, still an issue in v105.0.5195.127).  It worked fine in v104 and prior versions of Chrome.  Not sure if this is a problem for 'other' types of scrolling grid containers or not, but it apparently is a problem for ag-grid objects that are contained in a horizontal flex container.  I will post the version that fixes it if/when I come across one.

Update on Sept. 28, 2022 - Chrome v106.x appears to have fixed this problem.

Comment: I just updated to Chrome browser v106.x (specifically, 106.0.5249.62, current release as of this post), and the issue causing my problems in v105 appears to be fixed.  added the additional line indicating this in the above answer.